# How to Combine svg Paths to One Path properly,I allways to make holes

Tags: svg, path, union

The origin svg flie in xaml format like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--This file is compatible with Silverlight-->
<Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Name="svg24" Width="1024" Height="1024">
  <Canvas.RenderTransform>
    <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
  </Canvas.RenderTransform>
  <Canvas.Resources/>
  <!--Unknown tag: sodipodi:namedview-->
  <Path Fill="#FF1296DB" Data="M496 30.4L472 72v880l24 41.6 24-41.6V72z"/>
  <Path Fill="#FF1296DB" Data="M496 240l-96-64v-48l96 64zM496 336L368 256v-48l128 80zM496 240l96-64v-48l-96 64zM496 336l128-80v-48L496 288zM496 784l-96 64v48l96-64zM496 688L368 768v48l128-80zM496 784l96 64v48l-96-64zM496 688l128 80v48L496 736z"/>
  <Path Fill="#FF1296DB" Data="M79.2 752.8h48l761.6-440 24-41.6h-48l-761.6 440z"/>
  <Path Fill="#FF1296DB" Data="M260 648l-7.2 115.2-41.6 24 7.2-115.2zM343.2 600l-5.6 151.2-41.6 24 5.6-151.2z"/>
  <Path  Fill="#FF1296DB" Data="M260 648l-103.2-51.2-41.6 24L218.4 672zM343.2 600l-133.6-70.4-41.6 24L301.6 624zM731.2 376l103.2 51.2 41.6-24L772.8 352zM648 424l133.6 71.2 41.6-24L689.6 400z"/>
  <Path  Fill="#FF1296DB" Data="M731.2 376l7.2-115.2 41.6-24-7.2 115.2zM648 424l5.6-150.4 41.6-24-5.6 150.4z"/>
  <Path  Fill="#FF1296DB" Data="M912.8 752.8h-48l-761.6-440-24-41.6h48l761.6 440z"/>
  <Path  Fill="#FF1296DB" Data="M732 648l7.2 115.2 41.6 24-7.2-115.2zM648.8 600l5.6 151.2 41.6 24-5.6-151.2z"/>
  <Path  Fill="#FF1296DB" Data="M732 648l103.2-51.2 41.6 24L773.6 672zM648.8 600l133.6-70.4 41.6 24L690.4 624zM260.8 376l-103.2 51.2-41.6-24L219.2 352zM344 424l-133.6 71.2-41.6-24L302.4 400zM260.8 376l-7.2-115.2-41.6-24 7.2 115.2z"/>
  <Path  Fill="#FF1296DB" Data="M344 424l-5.6-150.4-41.6-24 5.6 150.4z"/>
  <Path  Fill="#FF1296DB" Data="M496 663.2l-131.2-75.2V436.8L496 360.8l131.2 75.2v151.2L496 663.2zM404.8 564.8L496 616.8l91.2-52.8v-104L496 407.2l-91.2 52.8v104.8z"/>
</Canvas>
```

the svg looks like here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKG7x.png)
I try to add some animation in WPF,so Have to merge the Path.
Use InkScape,Select All,Convert to Path,and Union,It is Combine to One Path,but looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxvuG.png)

What happened,and how to Combine without Holes? Thank you.

any method (WPF,inkscape or svg File) to combine paths properyl.

Comment: In inkscape: 1. Select all. 2. Apply "object/ungroup" operation multiple times multiple times until you see bounding box rectangles around your paths. 3. Run "path/unite"

Answer (score 2):

You need a `fill-rule="evenodd"`

- Use a a decent SVG editor, like VS-Code
- Add a *Preview SVG* extension so you can see your changes live
- Then **manually** concatenate all `Data` values.
- And paste it into the `d` attribute:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" style="background:pink">
  <path fill="blue" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M496 30.4L472 72v880l24 41.6 24-41.6V72z"/>
</svg>
```